# difference between mongoclientoptions vs mongoclientsettings

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java-3.8

what are the major differences between `mongoclientoptions vs mongoclientsettings`

Can anyone please give an example and elaborate where to use what with example?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer from what I can tell is the `MongoClientOptions` is the old way, whereas `MongoClientSettings` is the new way.

The newest MongoDB Java driver (3.9 at time of writing this answer) supports the old client - i.e., com.mongodb.MongoClient() which takes as a parameter MongoClientOptions.  See https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html.

The newer client has a different namespace - it is com.mongodb.client.MongoClient().  This client expects to be built using com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(), which takes a MongoClientSettings.  See https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoClients.html